# Where can I find an Ebony Helmet?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I want to get an ebony helmet from somewhere, and I don't have a high enough smithing to make one. Where is the best place I can find one?

Comment: "Don't have a high enough smithing"? That doesn't make sense! Didn't you power level smithing?

Comment: As far as I know, no sure place. What level are you?

Comment: @Coomie Smithing isn't mandatory. I have zero interest in it and am doing fine.

Comment: I found 1 somewhere at high level 20's, I think it was at a dragon home or at the end of a dungeon but it it is definitely possible to find one.

Comment: @Coomie he has a low smithing level.

Answer (score 12):

Boss chests at the end of a dungeon are your best bet, since those things are random. Keep in mind that ebony armor will only start showing up after you reach level 32, and even then not frequently.

At higher levels, mercenaries (a random encounter) will have a chance to be equipped in ebony, apart from those ebony armor is very rare.

Answer (score 6):

You can get a FULL ebony but it doesn't give you the helmet if you do the easy quest Boethians Calling. The armour is enchanted with silent movement and enemies who get too close get automatically poisoned for 5 dps. Nice for such an easy quest, just take a follower and it's no bother.

Answer (score 3):

Go to any dragon icon on the map and there should be a Boss chest. Save, then loot the chest. Since the chest contents are random, if you don't get one, reload and try again. As long as you are at a high enough level, around 32-34, i think, you should eventually get one.

Answer (score 2):

If you have the [Dragonborn DLC](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Dragonborn:Dragonborn) installed:

Upon reaching level 80, a [mysterious warrior](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Dragonborn:The_Ebony_Warrior) wearing a full suit of ebony armor will approach you in any major city, such as Whiterun, and challenge you to a duel at his "last vigil".

He will always be equipped with the following items: Ebony Armor of Regeneration, Ebony Boots of Frost Suppression, Ebony Gauntlets of Extreme Wielding, and an Ebony Helmet of Waterbreathing, as well as a Necklace of Shock Suppression and a Ring of Peerless Wielding.

...once you have defeated the Ebony Warrior, the quest will conclude and you may loot his body for his fully enchanted set of equipment.

<sup>Source:

http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Dragonborn:The_Ebony_Warrior

http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Dragonborn:Ebony_Warrior</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I got mine from filnjar, a silversmith in shor's stone. having trouble finding it? Its north of riftin, next to fort greenwall.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much any armor merchant will carry high-level equipment for all slots and of all materials, including ebony, once you have high enough level, which is 32 for ebony armor. They will also start appearing in random chests on same level and on monsters with that level and above.

Answer (score 0):

You can find ebony armor when you're level 30 and above while in a fortress. My advice is to find Robber's Gorge and kill the bandits until you reach a chest. When I did that I found my first ebony peice, a Ebony Sword, and then after that ebony armor, gauntlets and boots.

Comment: I find it very hard to believe that the boss chest at Robber's Gorge has a higher chance of having ebony armor than any other boss chest.

Answer (score 0):

I find ebony in almost every chest at the end of a dungion and I'm level 38, also if you have it and your conjuration is level 90 or above talk to Phinis Gester at the college of Winterhold (after joining the college). Then ask if there's anything else I can learn about conjuration. He will then gives you a really short quest and you get a sigil stone you can place at the atronach forge. Next, make deadric items by having the ebony item you want to turn into the same type of deadric item (except you can't get deadric boots for some reason), a black soul gem, a dwarven centurion core, and a deadra heart. After that you put that in the offering box and pull the handle (if your conjuration isn't 90 buy soul trap from the same guy and keep casting it on a dead animal). I was level 56 an it took me like 15 minutes but it does work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an ebony sword dead mans respite is an excellent spot. Either find it in a chest, loot it from draugr, or kill king Olaf

Answer (score -1):

You can find them in a Draugr Deathlord chests in some dungeons, although you need to be level 32+.